# Android: Dialog Fragment and Backstack problems

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragmenttransaction

So lets say I have the following Fragments:

Fragment1
Fragment2
DialogFragment
Fragment3
Fragment4

Lets say I go to the following Fragments, each fragmetn is added to the back stack:

```
Fragment1 -> Fragment2 -> DialogFragment -> Fragment3 -> Fragment4
```

If I click the BACK button this should normally go to **Fragment3** but instead **DialogFragment** is displayed.

Here are the Fragment Transactions I used:

**Fragment1 -> Fragment2**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.mainContentHolder, new Fragment2(), "Fragment2");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

**Fragment2 -> DialogFragment**

```
FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft2.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.flipp_in,R.anim.flipp_static);
ft2.add(R.id.mainContentHolder, new DialogFragment(), "DialogFragment");
ft2.addToBackStack(null);   
ft2.commit();
ft2.hide(Fragment1.this);
```

**DialogFragment -> Fragment3**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.mainContentHolder, new Fragment3(), "Fragment3");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

**Fragment3 -> Fragment4**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                                           
ft.replace(R.id.mainContentHolder, new Fragment4(), "Fragment4");
ft.addToBackStack(null);                        
ft.commit();
```

Again the problem is that when I'm in Fragment4 and click the BACK button the DialogFragment is displayed instead of Fragment3.

Answer (score 0):

Please use fragment manager of your Activity in Fragments when showing DialogFragment to avoid restoring it from back stack.